# How can I show the combobox selected value in a text box‎ C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, combobox, ado.net

I'm new in this and I'm a little lost. 
Trying to show the values of my database in textbox by selecting in the combobox. But I can't. 
Please help me. This is my code:

```
    private void CargarDatos()
        {
            string consulta = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[alumno]";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.conexion);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            con.Close();

            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            cbalumno.DataSource = dt;
            cbalumno.DisplayMember="Nombre";
            cbalumno.ValueMember="Id";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CargarDatos();
        }

        private void cbalumno_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The parameters that i want to show are "Name" "Surname" and "DNI" of the table alumno.

Any ideas to how can I do that??

Comment: First move `con.Close();` to `finally` block to close connection if error occurs. Now actually you required multi-value combo box which will show multiple columns as per `DataTable` you have to design that one for you or you can use DevExpress [`LookUpEdit`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdittopic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have placed the event `cbalumno_SelectedIndexChanged` in your code and now you have to use it.

Inside that event, just use the `Text` peroperty of that textbox and assign the value of the selected item in your combo box like this :

```
private void cbalumno_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        yourTextBoxID.Text = comboBoxID.Text;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did this and in my three textbox showed me only the value of the nombretxtbox:


 private void cbalumno_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
            nombretextBox.Text = cbalumno.Text;
            apellidotextBox.Text = cbalumno.Text;
            citextBox.Text = cbalumno.Text;
        }

Comment: That might be because the other two comboBoxes dont have any selected  item on them. Try selecting some text on them two and then on this third one and then check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataRowView` to get the record being bound with current `SelectedItem`. The `Row` property of `DataRowView` object will give you data row. Using this row you can get the columns being bound to it.

```
private void cbalumno_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DataRowView vrow = (DataRowView)cbalumno.SelectedItem;
     string sValue = vrow.Row["Name"].ToString();
}
```